# How to include necessary dll's in InstallShield Project Assistant?

Tags: c#, installshield

I have absolutely no concern at this stage of a prototype for the size of an application.  What is more important is that it has everything it needs to run.

My first C# app.  I'm using InstallShield 2013 Limited Edition.  How do I specify this in the little InstallSheild Project Assistant?

[image]

I need the setup.exe that is produced (path\to\InstallerProject\Express\SingleImage\DiskImages\setup.exe)

to include my dlls, somewhat like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any DLLs referenced in your project will be included in the Project/Primary outputs. Any additional files can be included with the 'Add Files' and 'Add Folders' features.

Comment: how am i supposed to know which dll's need to be manually included?  shouldn't that come from everything in my references?

Comment: You'll need to manually add any dlls that aren't directly referenced by your project

Comment: How do I know WHAT is not directly referenced in the first place?

Comment: Look in the project references list in Visual Studio

Comment: solved my problem. but it seems so weird ! It should have copied all referenced dlls of given output project by itself